# Hypergraph modeling in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (hank)-[]->(hyperedge)-[]->(cletus)
```

If Hank has multiple relationships to hyperedge and/or hyperedge has multiple relationships to Cletus, but there is only one relationship *from* Hank *through* hyperedge *to* Cletus, will this query give me that relationship?

Assuming the answer to that is yes, if I do this:

```
CREATE (hank)-[:FOO]->(hyperedge)-[:BAR]->(cletus)
```

will

```
MATCH (hank)-[:FOO]->(hyperedge)-[:BAR]->(cletus)
```

give me the relationship I just created, if Hank has multiple `FOO` relationships to hyperedge and/or hyperedge has multiple `BAR` relationships to Cletus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, if hank, hyperedge and cletus are fixed, then yes,

Otherwise you probably want to use:

```
MATCH shortestPath((hank)-[:FOO]->(hyperedge)-[:BAR]->(cletus))
```

to get only one.

Otherwise you have to "tag" that relationship somehow, e.g. with a property.

```
MATCH (hank)-[:FOO {tag:1}]->(hyperedge)-[:BAR  {tag:1}]->(cletus)
```